# Malformed declaration expecting version

Tags: magento-1.9, error

getting this error and honestly don't know where to start search for the problem.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Malformed declaration expecting version  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 451

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/var/www/html/m...', 451, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(451): simplexml_load_string('getFileLayoutUpdatesXml('frontend', 'rwd', 'default', '1')
#3 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(347): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchFileLayoutUpdates()
#4 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(246): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchPackageLayoutUpdates('default')
#5 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(224): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->merge('default')
#6 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(306): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->load()
#7 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(109): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayoutUpdates()
#8 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Any helping suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last layout xml file you changed contains error. In case you have a backup of that file revert those changes or else to debug the same go to
/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450 and place the code

```
Mage::log(print_r($filename, true));
```

Make sure your logging is turned on check the file names that are dumped into the log, the last file that you get is probably the error prone check for the errors (spaces, unclosed tags etc.) once you resolve that the error will dissappear